# SSL error on Firebase hosting on old Android devices

Tags: browser, https

I am not being able to see my Firebase Web App on old Android Devices due to SSL error.

[image: Chome on Android showing "SSL connection error" message]

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585697/firebase-hosting-ssl-handshake-exception-on-android-4-4) about this, but the answer doesn't say how to solve it.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

**SSL/TLS support is based on the Android version.** There's no way for Android end-users to fix this issue unless to upgrade to a newer Android version if possible.

In this case, based on [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=plasmatuhistoria.com&s=151.101.65.195&hideResults=on), the site only supports TLS 1.2.

[image: The site configuration only supports TLS 1.2]

TLS 1.2 is only supported since [Android 4.4.2 KitKat](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=4.4.2&key=62), where [Android 4.3 Jelly Bean](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Android&version=4.3&key=61) and before only supports TLS 1.0 (among other older protocols).

[image: A list of Android versions not supporting TLS 1.2, from Android 4.3 and older]

The only fix is to configure the server to allow other protocols and/or cipher suites (the specific depends on the server and out-of-scope of this site).