# Updating old Android Jellybean (4.2.2) Device

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

My friend has just dug out an old Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7.0.  It looks like it hasn't been used in a long time, and hasn't been updated in years.  It doesn't support TLS 1.2 and is missing updates to Trusted Root CAs.

If I open Play Store it goes into a loop of "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped" messages and I have to reboot it.  I've tried clearing all the cache data for Play Store and Play Services apps, but it hasn't helped.

I did some searching about support for TLS 1.2 on Android 4.2.2 (which is what it's running) and found that it supports TLS 1.2 but is disabled by default.  But every post I find about enabling this refers to doing so in the API while building an app, rather than on the device itself.

Does anybody have any thoughts/ideas on how I can get some updates installed onto this device so that it'll start talking TLS1.2 ?  Is there any http only site that I could download some updates from for example ?

I did try going into About > Check for Updates but it says that it's already got the latest.  I'm not too sure if this is just because it can't talk to any updates server or if it's correct.  Seems like there'd have to be some way of supporting TLS 1.2 on these older devices ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI, TLS is coupled with Android version. [Android officially supports TLS 1.2 from Android 4.4.2 KitKat](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/229959/44325)

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't joined the site after the question was migrated, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_2_7.0) for this device, officially, it only supported 4.2.2 at the highest.

You'd need to update it using a third-party software, such as [LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/).

That said, the tablet itself is outside of even their maintenance window, and depending on which device you have (the [Cellular](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/espresso3g) version or the [Wifi](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/espressowifi) version), will need to manually build their latest OS for it.

All the standard disclaimers about modifying your android device with aftermarket software remain relevant here.

Comment: Just pointing to LineageOS is not helpful if the device is no longer supported...

Answer (score 0):

I would go over to XDA and root it:

`https://www.xda-developers.com/easy-root-and-recovery-tutorial-for-the-galaxy-tab-2-7-0/`

and then choose one of their roms and flash it:

`https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-2/7-inch-development`

Comment: Is there a reason why you add the links in a non-clickable way?